# Not able to replace the string containing $ in pandas column

Tags: python, string, pandas, series

I have a `dataframe`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[5, '12$sell', '1$sell']})
```

I want to replace **$sell** from column b.

So I tried `replace()` method like below

```
df['b'] = df['b'].str.replace("$sell","")
```

but it's doesn't replace the given string and it gives me same dataframe as original.

It's working when I use it with `apply`

```
df['b'] = df['b'].apply(lambda x: str(x).replace("$sell",""))
```

So I want to know why it is not working in previous case?

Note: I tried replacing only **$** and shockingly it works.

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) before you posted? What did you learn from it? Why didn't it answer your question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is regex metacharacter (end of string), escape it or add parameter `regex=False`:

```
df['b'] = df['b'].str.replace("\$sell","")
print (df)
   a    b
0  1  NaN
1  2   12
2  3    1
```

---

```
df['b'] = df['b'].str.replace("$sell","", regex=False)
```

If want also value 5, what is numeric, use [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) with regex=True for replace substrings - numeric values are not touched:

```
df['b'] = df['b'].replace("\$sell","", regex=True)

print (df['b'].apply(type))
0    <class 'int'>
1    <class 'str'>
2    <class 'str'>
Name: b, dtype: object
```

Or cast to strings all data of column:

```
df['b'] = df['b'].astype(str).str.replace("$sell","", regex=False)

print (df['b'].apply(type))
0    <class 'str'>
1    <class 'str'>
2    <class 'str'>
Name: b, dtype: object
```

And for better performance if no missing values is possible use list comprehension:

```
df['b'] = [str(x).replace("$sell","") for x in  df['b']]

print (df)
   a   b
0  1   5
1  2  12
2  3   1
```

Comment: You need to escape the backslash or use a raw string.

Answer (score 4):

```
df['b'] = df['b'].str.replace("$sell","", regex=False)
```

Answer (score 4):

`$` is a regex special character. By default, [`pd.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) uses `regex=True`.

Instead, specify `regex=False`:

```
df['b'] = df['b'].str.replace('$sell', '', regex=False)
```

Answer (score 4):

str.replace assumes a regex is being used. so you need to use escape i.e.

```
df['b'] = df['b'].str.replace("\$sell","")
```